# How to move only non-directory files

Tags: linux, directory, mv

Say I am organizing a dir. It looked like this:

```
.
├── file_a.adoc
├── file_a.c
├── file_a.py
├── file_b.adoc
├── file_b.c
├── file_b.py
├── file_c.adoc
├── file_c.c
└── file_c.py
```

and now I'm at this point:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── file_a.adoc
│   ├── file_a.c
│   └── file_a.py
├── b
│   ├── file_b.adoc
│   ├── file_b.c
│   └── file_b.py
├── c
├── file_c.adoc
├── file_c.c
└── file_c.py
```

I want a command that can move all remaining non-directory files into dir c.

In this example I can use

```
mv *_c* c
```

but in more realistic scenarios, you might not have a good pattern to latch onto, or might not care to determine one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is the literal translation of "move everything that is a file into c":

```
for f in *; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then mv "$f" c; fi; done
```

Or avoiding the if-then verbosity:

```
for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv "$f" c; done
```

better, without it failing in a `set -e` shell:

```
for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv "$f" c || true; done
```

My preference, failing if and only if one of the moves fails:

```
for f in *; do [ ! -f "$f" ] || mv "$f" c; done
```

Literally: for every f, either it is not a file, or it is moved to c, or we abort.

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to pipe some `find` output into the `mv` command to avoid the `for` and `if` start and end syntax? Something like `mv \`find . -f *\` c`.

Comment: This would also move files that happened to be symbolic links to regular files. This may not be an issue in this particular instance, but the `-f` test is true for both regular files and for symbolic links to regular files.

Comment: @young_souvlaki You almost _never_ want to use the output of `find` for any further processing.

Comment: @Kusalananda it would indeed move symbolic links as well, but not to regular files. The symlinks remain symlinks. And all relative symlinks (except those pointing at a file in `.`) would break.

Comment: @young_souvlaki in theory you could do this with `find . -type f -exec mv {} c \;` **but** `find` recurses over subdirectories. Even if that were your intention, you'll still get in trouble as `find` will attempt to move the files it has just moved into `c` into `c` again.

Comment: @young_souvlaki @zwets there's `-maxdepth` though. Besides, it does not prevent the final result from being achieved anyway.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460482/exclude-a-sub-directory-using-find/25113492

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
mv -- *(.) c
```

This expands the `*` globbing pattern, but the globbing qualifier `(.)` filters this to only include names of regular files.  These are then given to the `mv` command and are all moved to the `c` directory.

From a non-`zsh` shell:

```bsh
zsh -c 'mv -- *(.) c'
```

Instead of using the globbing qualifier `(.)` to only select names of regular files, you could use `(^/)` which literally means "non-directory".  The difference being that `*(^/)` would also match names of symbolic links and other non-directory file types.

Comment: Does this answer assume all normal filenames have a `.` in them?

Comment: @young_souvlaki It does not.

Comment: @young_souvlaki Would you _want_ it to be restricted to filenames containing at least one dot, then use `*.*(.)` instead. This restricts it to only match regular files whose names contains a dot.

Comment: No it's good that this answer does not depend on the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in a b c; do
  mkdir "$i" # use -p if you need it
  find . -type f -name "*_$i.*" -exec mv -t "$i" {} + # or, mv {} "$i" \;
done
```